# Unable to run MPI when transfering large data

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I used `MPI_Isend` to transfer an array of chars to slave node. When the size of the array is small it worked, but when I enlarge the size of the array, it hanged there.

Code running on the master node (rank 0) :

```
MPI_Send(&text_length,1,MPI_INT,dest,MSG_TEXT_LENGTH,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Isend(text->chars, 360358,MPI_CHAR,dest,MSG_SEND_STRING,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
MPI_Wait(&request,&status);
```

Code running on slave node (rank 1):

```
MPI_Recv(&count,1,MPI_INT,0,MSG_TEXT_LENGTH,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
MPI_Irecv(host_read_string,count,MPI_CHAR,0,MSG_SEND_STRING,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
MPI_Wait(&request,&status);
```

You see the count param in `MPI_Isend` is `360358`. It seemed too large for `MPI`. When I set the param `1024`, it worked well.

Actually this problem has confused me a few days, I have known that there's limit on the size of data transferred by `MPI`. But as far as I know, the `MPI_Send` is used to send short messages, and the `MPI_Isend` can send larger messages. So I use `MPI_Isend`.

The network configure in rank 0 is:

```
  [12t2007@comp01-mpi.gpu01.cis.k.hosei.ac.jp ~]$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1B:21:D9:79:A5  
          inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:393267 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:396421 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:35556328 (33.9 MiB)  TX bytes:79580008 (75.8 MiB)

eth0.2002 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1B:21:D9:79:A5  
          inet addr:10.111.2.36  Bcast:10.111.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:133577 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:127677 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:14182652 (13.5 MiB)  TX bytes:17504189 (16.6 MiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1B:21:D9:79:A4  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:206981 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:303185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:168952610 (161.1 MiB)  TX bytes:271792020 (259.2 MiB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:91:6B:56  
          inet addr:10.111.1.36  Bcast:10.111.1.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26459977 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15700862 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12533940345 (11.6 GiB)  TX bytes:2078001873 (1.9 GiB)
          Memory:fb120000-fb140000 

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:91:6B:57  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Memory:fb100000-fb120000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1894012 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1894012 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:154962344 (147.7 MiB)  TX bytes:154962344 (147.7 MiB)
```

The network configure in rank 1 is:

```
[12t2007@comp02-mpi.gpu01.cis.k.hosei.ac.jp ~]$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1B:21:D9:79:5F  
          inet addr:192.168.0.102  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:328449 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:278631 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:47679329 (45.4 MiB)  TX bytes:39326294 (37.5 MiB)

eth0.2002 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1B:21:D9:79:5F  
          inet addr:10.111.2.37  Bcast:10.111.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:94126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:53782 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:8313498 (7.9 MiB)  TX bytes:6929260 (6.6 MiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1B:21:D9:79:5E  
          inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:121527 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41865 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:158117588 (150.7 MiB)  TX bytes:5084830 (4.8 MiB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:91:6B:50  
          inet addr:10.111.1.37  Bcast:10.111.1.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26337628 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15500750 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12526923258 (11.6 GiB)  TX bytes:2032767897 (1.8 GiB)
          Memory:fb120000-fb140000 

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:91:6B:51  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Memory:fb100000-fb120000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1895944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1895944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:154969511 (147.7 MiB)  TX bytes:154969511 (147.7 MiB)
```

Comment: It's a little unclear from your question what the code is actually doing. Can you post a minimum working example? (http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: There's no reason that you shouldn't be able to use either `MPI_Send` or `MPI_Isend` for either large or small messages. Usually the problem is that the send and receive calls aren't matching up correctly. This is especially true if things work for small messages and not for large ones.

Comment: Short messages fly directly to the destination via the so-called eager protocol, no matter if a matching receive has been posted or not. Larger messages require some interaction between the receiver and the sender and won't make it through until both sides match. Also it could be that your network is misconfigured (if rank 0 and rank 1 are located on physically separate machines and TCP/IP is used in-between).

Comment: @WesleyBland I just wanna translate a string from rank 0 to rank 1, for example, I wanna translate "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..", if the mount of 'a' is 1024, it works, but if the mount of 'a' is 1024000, if fails. Thank you.

Comment: @HristoIliev Yes, actually the rank 0 and rank 1 are located on physically separate machines and it seems like that TCP/IP is used. As  far as I know, when MPI translates large data it will use Rendezvous protocal, but my cluster is not so big that it contains a distributed file system, just a NFS, so I think the cluster doesn't support large data transferring. :(

Comment: Cluster size has nothing to do with MPI message size. It's Open MPI that tries to use all available network interfaces to increase the bandwidth and that leads to problems when the network is misconfigured. Could you please run "ifconfig -a" on both nodes and post the result in your question.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks for your concerning. I have post the network configure in my question, I think I should note that the cluster is administratted by my school, so I have no priority to change the configure. If the information helps, please tell me, thank you.

Comment: The nodes have multiple interfaces active. That could lead to problems with Open MPI. Try running your executable with the following additional options to `mpiexec` (or `mpirun`): `--mca btl_tcp_if_include eth0 --mca oob_tcp_if_include eth0`. Also try with `eth2` instead of `eth0` as it looks like there is a lot of traffic going over eth2, though it could be the NFS.

Comment: @HristoIliev I have reduced the size of the transferred data,  when I transferred the data many times it still hanged, but when I did as you said above, it worked!! Although I don't know why now... but it really helps. Thank you.

Comment: I'll post a detailed explanation why later on.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks a lot, if you'd like to post it as an answer， I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @HristoIliev Hi, it's me again :). Thanks for your helping, but I met another problem... would you mind looking over it ? It is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688207/what-should-i-do-if-i-want-to-send-message-by-mpi-and-receive-messages-at-the-sa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The peculiarities of using TCP/IP with Open MPI are described in the [FAQ](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tcp). I'll try to give an executive summary here.

Open MPI uses a greedy approach when it comes to utilising network interfaces for data exchange. In particular, the TCP/IP BTL (Byte Transfer Layer) and OOB (Out-Of-Band) components `tcp` will try to use all configured network interfaces with matching address families. In your case each node has many interfaces with addresses from the IPv4 address family:

```
comp01-mpi                     comp02-mpi
----------------------------------------------------------
eth0       192.168.0.101/24    eth0       192.168.0.102/24
eth0.2002  10.111.2.36/24      eth0.2002  10.111.2.37/24
eth1       192.168.1.101/24    eth1       192.168.1.102/24
eth2       10.111.1.36/23      eth2       10.111.1.37/23
lo         127.0.0.1/8         lo         127.0.0.1/8
```

Open MPI assumes that each interface on `comp02-mpi` is reachable from any interface on `comp01-mpi` and vice versa. This is never the case with the loopback interface `lo`, therefore by default Open MPI excludes `lo`. Network sockets are then opened lazily (e.g. on demand) when information has to be transported.

What happens in your case is that when transporting messages, Open MPI chops them down into fragments and then tries to send the different segments over different connections in order to maximise the bandwidth. By default the fragments are of size 128 KiB, which only holds 32768 `int` elements, also the very first (eager) fragment is of size 64 KiB and holds twice as less elements. It might happen that the assumption that each interface on `comp01-mpi` is reachable from each interface on `comp02-mpi` (and vice versa) is wrong, e.g. if some of them are connected to separate isolated networks. In that case the library will be stuck in trying to make a connection that can never happen and the program will hang. This should usually happen for messages of more than 16384 `int` elements.

To prevent the above mentioned situation, one can restrict the interfaces or networks that Open MPI uses for TCP/IP communication. The `btl_tcp_if_include` MCA parameter can be used to provide the library with the list of interfaces that it should use. The `btl_tcp_if_exclude` can be used to instruct the library which interfaces to exclude. That one is set to `lo` by default and if one would like to exclude specific interface(s), then one should explicitly add `lo` to the list.

Everything from above also applies to the out-of-band communication used to transport special information. The parameters for selecting or deselecting interfaces for OOB are `oob_tcp_if_include` and `oob_tcp_if_exclude` conversely. Those are usually set together with the BTL parameters. Therefore you should try setting those to combinations that actually work. Start by narrowing the selection down the a single interface:

```
 mpiexec --mca btl_tcp_if_include eth0 --mca oob_tcp_if_include eth0 ...
```

If it doesn't work with `eth0`, try other interfaces.

The presence of the virtual interface `eth0.2002` is going to further confuse Open MPI 1.6.2 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `360358` you must use `text_length` while sending the message (in function `MPI_Isend`) from rank=0.

I believe the reason why you are sending the length first is to eliminate the need to hard-code the number, then why are you putting the number of elements when sending to other nodes? That could be the reason for inconsistency at the receiving end.

The signature of MPI_Isend is:

```
int MPI_Isend(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Request *request)
```

where `count` is the number of elements in send buffer. It might lead to segmentation fault if `count` is more than the array length, or will lead to sending less elements across if the `count` is less.

Comment: Opps, actually both the value of text_length and count are 360358. I am sure the array is large enough.